# Can I rotate a Cartopy Projection to make the figure show the country of interest in the vertical orientation?

Tags: rotation, projection, figure, cartopy, displayobject

I'm doing a Stereographic Cartopy projection of some Greenland ice sheet data. When I plot the projection without any attributes, I get a slightly rotated Greenland. When I set the central_latitude and central_longitude to center over Greenland, it turns Greenland so that it's horizontal. I need to display the figure vertically. I'm able to rotate the entire resulting image but then the colorbar and title are still along the long sides of the figure.

ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], projection=ccrs.Stereographic(central_latitude=42.6043, central_longitude=71.7069)) gives a [horizontal Greenland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZweu.png)

ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], projection=ccrs.Stereographic() gives a [slightly rotated Greenland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrAQy.png)

Using

angle = 90

out = im.rotate(angle, expand=True)

just rotates the entire image, not the figure, [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OyLo.png)

Is it possible to rotate the projection/figure so that Greenland is centered vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is correct, but your coordinates seem off. Greenland is not located at a latitude of 42 nor at a longitude of 71. The point you specify is somewhere in the North West of Kyrgyzstan:
https://www.google.com/maps/@42.604,71.707,12z

Perhaps you flipped longitude and latitude, and assumed that the longitude of 42 means west? The [common way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Values) to express longitude to be positive for east and negative for west, which is also what Cartopy does, so for Greenland 42W should be specified as -42 instead.

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

projection = ccrs.Stereographic(central_latitude=70, central_longitude=-42)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(6, 12), facecolor="w",
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=projection),
)

ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
ax.set_extent((-65, -15, 58, 84), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[image]